# Python Application on IBM Bluemix / Dependency Missing in Manifest at Push Command

Tags: python, ibm-cloud

How can I modify the manifest in order to use latest 2.7 Python version supported by the default build-pack (2.7.11) and push my application into the Bluemix hosting server and why does it address the older release 2.7.6?

My command is:

cf push myapp -m 128 -c "python server.py"

See the resulting error below:

```
C:\Python\myprojects\ABC>cf push myapp -m 128M -c "python server.py"

-----> Downloaded app package (6.2M)
    -------> Buildpack version 1.5.5
 !     Warning: Your application is missing a Procfile. This file tells Heroku how to run your application.
 !     Learn more: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile
-----> Installing python-2.7.6
DEPENDENCY MISSING IN MANIFEST: python 2.7.6
It looks like you're trying to use python 2.7.6.
Unfortunately, that version of python is not supported by this buildpack.
The versions of python supported in this buildpack are:
- 3.5.1
- 3.5.0
- 3.4.4
- 3.4.3
- 3.3.6
- 3.3.5
- 2.7.11
- 2.7.10
If you need further help, start by reading: http://github.com/cloudfoundry/python-buildpack/releases.
Staging failed: Buildpack compilation step failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got a similar problem with python3, from the doc you don't handle that in the manifest file but in a runtime.txt at the root of your app, it just contains `python-3.5.1` for me so it must be `python-2.7.11` for you.

Comment: That is correct, the buildpack uses runtime.txt to specify which python version should be installed, and it will only work if the version specified in that file is supported by the buildpack.  Alternatively, you can omit the runtime.txt to always use the buildpack's default version (currently 2.7.12 in the 1.5.12 buildpack version).

Comment: Thanks for the quick support. Updating the runtime.txt file solved the issue.